# Is it possible to set: "show block on specific pages" into "is only the listed pages", programmatically?

Tags: blocks

Is it possible to set: "show block on specific pages" into "is only the listed pages"?

I suppose that I should add a new item in this block info, but I don't know which one and can't find it in the api hook_block_info();
This block should be only visible in the page overview_courses/course but is visible in every page except overview_course/course

```
function menuNode_block_info() {
  $blocks['Course'] = array(
    'info' => t('Dit toont alle blocken weer'),
    'region' => 'sidebar_first',
    'weight' => 1,
    'status' => 1,
    'pages' => "overview_courses/course",
    'cache' => 'DRUPAL_NO_CACHE',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

Can someone help me? all help is welcome.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set,  visibility => 'BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED'

```
function menuNode_block_info() {
  $blocks['Course'] = array(
    'info' => t('Dit toont alle blocken weer'),
    'region' => 'sidebar_first',
    'weight' => 1,
    'status' => 1,
    'visibility' => 'BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED',
    'pages' => "overview_courses/course",
    'cache' => 'DRUPAL_NO_CACHE',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```